# How to access the text within two tags from the codebehind

Tags: asp.net

I have a `Repeater` which has `HyperLinks` inside of it. This gets binded at the `OnInit()` method. The `HyperLinks` look like:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hl" NavigateUrl='<%# GetNotificationDetailsUrl(Eval("Id")) %>' Target="_blank"> <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "~/Images/Notifications/" + Eval("Type") + ".png" %>' /> <%# ResolveMessage(Container.DataItem) %> </asp:HyperLink>
```

So, there is text within two tags rather than in the `Text` attribute (notice the `Image`).

Is there any way to access this text at the `Page_Load` method (ie. once everything is binded)? I want to loop through the `Repeater` and check if the text="foo" etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the text="foo" during data binding, not after databinding.

[Repeater.ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx)